# Whats means autoresize = W+H in a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Can someone explain what this property means **autoresize = W+H**  ? 
is this the reason that i can't change the scroll view content size ?
how can i disable that property ? thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091484/uiview-resizes-subview

Comment: The issue is that you're using auto layout. When using auto layout, the way you change the scroll view content size is create constraints between the scroll view and its subviews. See [TN5154](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Autoresize = W + H makes sure subviews width and height is adjusted when view size changes, below are some more options.

```
RM = UIAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin
BM = UIAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin
W = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth 
H = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight
```

UIScrollView does not know the height of its content automatically. You should calculate the height and width, below method should be handy

```
CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;
for (UIView *view in self.scrollView.subviews) {
    contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, view.frame);
}
self.scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size;
```

Hope this helps !